# Sorting a tree while maintaining structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, materialized-path-pattern

I have a tree using materialized path.

The table is similar to:

```
+-------------+--------+----------+-------+
| path        | depth  | children | score |
+-------------+--------+----------+-------+
| 0001        | 1      | 3        | 5     |
| 00010001    | 2      | 0        | -3    |
| 00010002    | 2      | 0        | 27    |
| 00010003    | 2      | 0        | 10    |
| 0002        | 1      | 2        | 12    |
| 00020001    | 2      | 0        | 0     |
| 00020002    | 2      | 1        | 3     |
| 00020002001 | 3      | 0        | 1     |
+-------------+--------+----------+-------+
```

I want to sort by the `score` column while maintaining the tree structure.
What matters is children are beneath their parents.

```
+-------------+--------+----------+-------+
| path        | depth  | children | score |
+-------------+--------+----------+-------+
| 0002        | 1      | 2        | 12    |
| 00020002    | 2      | 1        | 3     |
| 00020002001 | 3      | 0        | 1     |
| 00020001    | 2      | 0        | 0     |
| 0001        | 1      | 3        | 5     |
| 00010002    | 2      | 0        | 27    |
| 00010003    | 2      | 0        | 10    |
| 00010001    | 2      | 0        | -3    |
+-------------+--------+----------+-------+
```

The `path` column is only used in the database, so it doesn't have to be sequential.

The SQL I currently use to sort the tree so I can build it:

```
SELECT path, depth, children, score FROM mytable ORDER BY path ASC
```

Comment: You could do an ORDER BY over multiple fields, sorting by path and score.

Comment: in your example required output, paths are shown descending, yet you state 'ASC' ?

Comment: As an aside, you could use an array for `path` so that you wouldn't have to worry about the zero-padding or four digit limitation.

Comment: If in this particular example the `00020001` item had the score of `2`, would it still have to retain the same position in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a recursive query and a window function. It'll look similar to this:

```
with recursive
ordered_tree as (
select tree.*,
       array[row_number() over w] as score_path
from   tree
where  depth = 1
window w as (order by tree.score desc)
union all
select tree.*,
       parent.score_path || array[row_number() over w] as score_path
from   tree
join   ordered_tree as parent on parent.id = tree.parent_id
window w as (partition by tree.parent_id order by tree.score desc)
)
select *
from   ordered_tree
order by score_path
```

Note: the above will be rather slow if your set is large...